# Array Search key and Replace value php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like

```
[{"detail":"33,putih","sku":"123","price":"500000","stok":"8"},{"detail":"33,hitam","sku":"123","price":"500000","stok":"5"},{"detail":"43,hitam","sku":"123","price":"1000000","stok":"1"}]
```

i have to json_decode it.

i want to change stok = 2 from detail "33,hitam".

but i'm seriously confused to use array search first and use array replace.

Comment: This is not a valid PHP array, there's nothing to `json_encode` here

Comment: I'm not sure `array_search` and `array_replace` sound the best tools for this job, but if you post what you've tried then we can help you a lot more easily

Comment: @gogaz yes sorry i means json_decode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this :

```
$stringarray = '[{"detail":"33,putih","sku":"123","price":"500000","stok":"8"},{"detail":"33,hitam","sku":"123","price":"500000","stok":"5"},{"detail":"43,hitam","sku":"123","price":"1000000","stok":"1"}]';
$array = json_decode($stringarray);
var_dump($array);
$replaced = replaceInObject($array, "detail", "33,hitam", "stok" , "2");
var_dump($replaced);

function replaceInObject($array, $field, $searchvalue, $valuefield, $newvalue){
    foreach($array as $element){
        if($element->$field == $searchvalue){
            $element->$valuefield = $newvalue;
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: Thx u so much, this is so flexible and helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to achieve this

```
$data = '[{"detail":"33,putih","sku":"123","price":"500000","stok":"8"},{"detail":"33,hitam","sku":"123","price":"500000","stok":"5"},{"detail":"43,hitam","sku":"123","price":"1000000","stok":"1"}]';
$json = json_decode($data, true);

$result = array_map(function($e) {
                        if ($e['detail'] == "33,hitam") $e['stok'] = "2";
                        return $e;
                    }, $json);
```

Comment: thx u @gogaz... but i miss one thing when i try $search = "33,hitam". and i use your solution if ($e['detail'] == $search) $e['stok'] = "2"; but $search not found, is this because mapping ?